# Youtube API v3 only finds the first 100 pages of a Playlist

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am currently working on a project, which tries to get all videoIds from the Upload-Playlist of the channel "[PietSmiet](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqwGaUvq_l0RKszeHhZ5leA)" (a German Let's Player with around 15,500 videos).

Finding the Id of the channel ("*UCqwGaUvq_l0RKszeHhZ5leA*") and the Id of the Upload-Playlist ("*UUqwGaUvq_l0RKszeHhZ5leA*") is easy and getting the first [fifty videos](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails%252Cstatus&maxResults=50&playlistId=UUqwGaUvq_l0RKszeHhZ5leA&_h=1&) of this list is possible too.

I know that one can see more pages/videos by setting/changing the pageToken,
but on the 100th page (pageToken="*CNYmEAA*") there is **no nextPageToken**, despite the fact, that there are 15414 videos overall in the playlist and that this page only shows the videos 4950-4999.

By changing the pageToken to "*CIcnEAA*" (this page starts at the 4999th video), I could get to the 5048th video, but there is still no nextPageToken.

Is this a bug or a limitation and is there a solution?